# Not able to store value getting from Transliteration using GWT

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and I want to make a application in which words are transliterate and store in a varible.which can be used for storing values in database.

But when I am trying to store in variable it gives null value when am printing it.

```
package com.google.gwt.language.sample.hellolanguage.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gwt.language.client.transliteration.LanguageCode;
import com.google.gwt.language.client.transliteration.SupportedDestinationLanguages;
import com.google.gwt.language.client.transliteration.control.TransliterationControl;
import com.google.gwt.language.client.transliteration.control.TransliterationControlOptions;
import com.google.gwt.language.client.transliteration.text.Transliteration;
import com.google.gwt.language.client.transliteration.text.TransliterationCallback;
import com.google.gwt.language.client.transliteration.text.TransliterationResult;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;





public class Trans extends Composite {


    ArrayList<String> wordsArray= new ArrayList<String>();
    public String sss;
    public void recieve(String ss)
    {
        this.sss=ss;
        System.out.println(sss);
    }


    public String send(){
         return sss;
    }

  public Trans(ArrayList<String> str) {


    initTransliterationControls(str);


//Here I want to print 
    System.out.println(sss);

  }

  public void initTransliterationControls(ArrayList<String> wordsArray1) {


    //ArrayList<String> wordsArray= new ArrayList<String>();
 //  wordsArray=wordsArray1;
    //System.out.println(wordsArray1.size());
   // for(int i=0;i<wordsArray1.size();i++)
    //{
        //wordsArray.add(wordsArray1.get(i).toString());
    //}
    wordsArray.add(wordsArray1.get(0).toString());
    wordsArray.add("Rerrebok");
    wordsArray.add("Woodland j_74_Hi-gh Heels Boots");


    //System.out.println(wordsArray);






    Transliteration.transliterate(wordsArray, LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        LanguageCode.HINDI, new TransliterationCallback() {

          @Override
          public void onCallback(TransliterationResult result) {
             // System.out.println(result.getTransliterations().toString());
              List<List<String>> collection= new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            collection=result.getTransliterations();


// Here I am storing it on sss but when I am print outside this function it gives Null

            sss=collection.get(0).get(0).toString();


          }

    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost, where are these bits of code running? Is some of it on the server called by GWT RPC? Use of System.out suggest the server but then it seems to be in a client side related Composite object..

Comment: "That's not async" http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/faca1575f306ba0f/3be719c021aa19bd - you need to not use the result before it is available.

Comment: My requirement as follow:- my requirement as follows:- I have a database and i have to fetch content of database and transliterate it and again save into the database. I fetched data using server side code through RPC and Transliterate it using google api. I am able to print it on client side console but unable to save it on DB.